# What is adclick remote address?

Tags: netstat

`netstat -a` returns the information below.

What is the "adclick" address? There is any benefit from disconnect it? How to shutdown that connection?

[image]

Comment: *"There is any benefit from disconnect it?"* - There is no point in disconnecting since it is not connected - it is a listening socket only. For some reason `0.0.0.0` is shown as `adclick` in the output. Do you have anything like this in your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system)? Also, does not seem to be related to security, i.e. off-topic.

Comment: What's your PC's name?